# How to update yaml file in python with section wise syntax?

Tags: python, yaml

I have an yaml file with syntax like this.

```
logJsonDataConfig: &logJsonDataConfig
  code: logJsonData
  path: /logs/
  ext: .json
queueJsonDataConfig: &queueJsonDataConfig
  code: queueJsonData
  path: /queue/
  ext: .json
gatewayGrpcConfig: &gatewayGrpcConfig
  code: gatewayGrpc
  driverName: tcp
  urlAddress: 0.0.0.0:5051
excelGrpcConfig: &excelGrpcConfig
  code: excelGrpc
  driverName: tcp
  urlAddress: 127.0.0.1:5052
adGrpcConfig: &adGrpcConfig
  code: adGrpc
  driverName: tcp
  urlAddress: 127.0.0.1:5053
restfulWebServiceGrpcConfig: &restfulWebServiceGrpcConfig
  code: restfulWebServiceGrpc
  driverName: tcp
  urlAddress: 127.0.0.1:5054
databaseGrpcConfig: &databaseGrpcConfig
  code: databaseGrpc
  driverName: tcp
  urlAddress: 127.0.0.1:5055
serviceDeskPlusGrpcConfig: &serviceDeskPlusGrpcConfig
  code: serviceDeskPlusGrpc
  driverName: tcp
  urlAddress: 127.0.0.1:5056
recordingAgentGrpcConfig: &recordingAgentGrpcConfig
  code: recordingAgentGrpc
  driverName: tcp
  urlAddress: 127.0.0.1:5057
fileAndFolderGrpcConfig: &fileAndFolderGrpcConfig
  code: fileAndFolderGrpc
  driverName: tcp
  urlAddress: 127.0.0.1:5058
pdfGrpcConfig: &pdfGrpcConfig
  code: pdfGrpc
  driverName: tcp
  urlAddress: 127.0.0.1:5059
ocrGrpcConfig: &ocrGrpcConfig
  code: ocrGrpc
  driverName: tcp
  urlAddress: 127.0.0.1:5060
ewsGrpcConfig: &ewsGrpcConfig
  code: ewsGrpc
  driverName: tcp
  urlAddress: 127.0.0.1:5061
zapConfig: &zapConfig
  code: zap
  level: debug
  enableCaller: true
logrusConfig: &logrusConfig
  code: logrus
  level: debug
  enableCaller: false
logConfig: *zapConfig
excelMicroserviceConfig: &excelMicroserviceConfig
  code: excelMicroservice
  logDataConfig: &logDataConfig
    code: logData
    dataStoreConfig: *logJsonDataConfig
activeDirectoryMicroserviceConfig: &activeDirectoryMicroserviceConfig
  code: activeDirectoryMicroservice
  logDataConfig: &logDataConfig
    code: logData
    dataStoreConfig: *logJsonDataConfig
restfulWebServiceMicroserviceConfig: &restfulWebServiceMicroserviceConfig
  code: restfulWebServiceMicroservice
  logDataConfig: &logDataConfig
    code: logData
    dataStoreConfig: *logJsonDataConfig
recordingAgentMicroserviceConfig: &recordingAgentMicroserviceConfig
  code: recordingAgentMicroservice
  logDataConfig: &logDataConfig
    code: logData
    dataStoreConfig: *logJsonDataConfig
databaseMicroserviceConfig: &databaseMicroserviceConfig
  code: databaseMicroservice
  logDataConfig: &logDataConfig
    code: logData
    dataStoreConfig: *logJsonDataConfig
serviceDeskPlusMicroserviceConfig: &serviceDeskPlusMicroserviceConfig
  code: serviceDeskPlusMicroservice
  logDataConfig: &logDataConfig
    code: logData
    dataStoreConfig: *logJsonDataConfig
fileAndFolderMicroserviceConfig: &fileAndFolderMicroserviceConfig
  code: fileAndFolderMicroservice
  logDataConfig: &logDataConfig
    code: logData
    dataStoreConfig: *logJsonDataConfig
pdfMicroserviceConfig: &pdfMicroserviceConfig
  code: pdfMicroservice
  logDataConfig: &logDataConfig
    code: logData
    dataStoreConfig: *logJsonDataConfig
ocrMicroserviceConfig: &ocrMicroserviceConfig
  code: ocrMicroservice
  logDataConfig: &logDataConfig
    code: logData
    dataStoreConfig: *logJsonDataConfig
ewsMicroserviceConfig: &ewsMicroserviceConfig
  code: ewsMicroservice
  logDataConfig: &logDataConfig
    code: logData
    dataStoreConfig: *logJsonDataConfig
useCaseConfig:
  logJson:
    code: logJson
  queue:
    code: queue
    logDataConfig: &logDataConfig
      code: logData
      dataStoreConfig: *queueJsonDataConfig
  excel:
    code: excel
    microserviceConfig: *excelMicroserviceConfig
    logDataConfig: &logDataConfig
      code: logData
      dataStoreConfig: *logJsonDataConfig
  activeDirectory:
    code: activeDirectory
    microserviceConfig: *activeDirectoryMicroserviceConfig
    logDataConfig: &logDataConfig
      code: logData
      dataStoreConfig: *logJsonDataConfig
  restfulWebService:
    code: restfulWebService
    microserviceConfig: *restfulWebServiceMicroserviceConfig
    logDataConfig: &logDataConfig
      code: logData
      dataStoreConfig: *logJsonDataConfig
  database:
    code: database
    microserviceConfig: *databaseMicroserviceConfig
    logDataConfig: &logDataConfig
      code: logData
      dataStoreConfig: *logJsonDataConfig
  serviceDeskPlus:
    code: serviceDeskPlus
    microserviceConfig: *serviceDeskPlusMicroserviceConfig
    logDataConfig: &logDataConfig
      code: logData
      dataStoreConfig: *logJsonDataConfig
  recordingAgent:
    code: recordingAgent
    microserviceConfig: *recordingAgentMicroserviceConfig
    logDataConfig: &logDataConfig
      code: logData
      dataStroreConfig: *logJsonDataConfig
  fileAndFolder:
    code: fileAndFolder
    microserviceConfig: *fileAndFolderMicroserviceConfig
    logDataConfig: &logDataConfig
      code: logData
      dataStoreConfig: *logJsonDataConfig
  pdf:
    code: pdf
    microserviceConfig: *pdfMicroserviceConfig
    logDataConfig: &logDataConfig
      code: logData
      dataStoreConfig: *logJsonDataConfig
  ocr:
    code: ocr
    microserviceConfig: *ocrMicroserviceConfig
    logDataConfig: &logDataConfig
      code: logData
      dataStoreConfig: *logJsonDataConfig
  ews:
    code: ews
    microserviceConfig: *ewsMicroserviceConfig
    logDataConfig: &logDataConfig
      code: logData
      dataStoreConfig: *logJsonDataConfig
  loop:
    code: loop
    logDataConfig: &logDataConfig
      code: logData
      dataStoreConfig: *logJsonDataConfig
  ifelse:
    code: ifElse
    logDataConfig: &logDataConfig
      code: logData
      dataStoreConfig: *logJsonDataConfig
```

The python modules are not working here lik pyyaml as the syntax is bit different but the yaml is still valid I have checked it with yaml [checker](http://www.yamllint.com/)

So, is there any module in python or any other language, I could add one more section like below if it is not there or simply update the existing one.

[snap to add in the yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrER0.png)

Please suggest, tried all modules but failing with this: pyyaml,python-benedict,ruamel.yaml

I tried [yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq), eventhough in different sections, it considered lements as duplicate.

```
python -m yq -Y .gatewayGrpcConfig .\input.yml
yq: Error running jq: ComposerError: found duplicate anchor 'logDataConfig'; first occurrence
  in ".\input.yml", line 64, column 18
second occurrence
  in ".\input.yml", line 69, column 18
```

Comment: Asking for libraries is off-topic on StackOverflow. Instead, you could describe in detail why you think PyYAML cannot process this (it can) so that we can help you processing the input with PyYAML.

Comment: I need to add the line in the snap above to the yaml file. Can you suggest how to do that.When I ran with pyyaml, the laoding of the file itself not working, I  assumed because of the section heading format (logJsonDataConfig: &logJsonDataConfig) instead of just (section_name:)

Comment: PyYAML does not like the duplicate anchors while composing, but you don't want to do that anyway because that will lose the anchor names. `for event in yaml.parse(input): print(event)` in Python does work with PyYAML and is what you want to work with here. You can also try [the other yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/) which is way better since it is actually designed to work with YAML structure, while python-yq just discards everything JSON doesn't have (including your anchors) and hurls it into `jq`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input is in the file `input.yaml`, there is no problem loading this with `ruamel.yaml`.
Just ignore the `ReusedAnchorWarning`:

```py
import sys
import warnings
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml

warnings.simplefilter("ignore", ruamel.yaml.error.ReusedAnchorWarning)
    
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(Path('input.yaml'))
print(data['useCaseConfig']['excel']['microserviceConfig']['logDataConfig']['dataStoreConfig']['path'])
```

which gives:

```
/logs/
```

Please note that the recommended extension for files containing YAML documents has been `.yaml` since September 2006.